# Attempting to reference a deleted function, VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

The following used to compile with Visual Studio 2013 but now gives the error, "attempting to reference a deleted function" in Visual Studio 2015.

```
template<typename... Args>
void operator()(Args && ... args)
{
    auto guard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(Mutex);
    {
        Clean();

        for (auto const & listener : Listeners)
        {
            if(auto locked = std::get<0>(listener).lock())              
                std::get<1>(listener)(args...);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is the first statement:

```
auto guard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(Mutex)
```

Mutex is just a std::mutex.  Can anyone shed any light on why this is now an error?

Edit: I'm also getting it here with this line of code too:

```
auto converter = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>();
```

Comment: Make it `const auto& guard = ...`. As written, `auto` resolves to `std::lock_guard`, and the initialization requires a copy constructor.

Comment: Ok, but const & means from_bytes can't be used in the following statements.

Comment: Just make it `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;`, and for that matter `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(Mutex);`

Comment: Yes, that was the answer. Thank you.

Comment: See question 6 [here](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see e.g. [this `std::lock_guard` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard) you will see that the copy-constructor, which is invoked in your declaration, is marked as deleted.

The simplest way to solve it is to *not* use the copy-constructor form of initialization, but direct initialization:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(Mutex);
```

Comment: Why did it compile in 2013?

Comment: VS2013 does not support implicit generation of move constructors and move assignment operators.

Comment: @LeFlou I know, but that still doesn't explain how it worked.

Comment: I'm willing to believe 2013 fixed the developer's error here behind the scenes (naughty) or didn't apply the rule correctly in the first place.  I suppose I'm a little zealous with AAA (almost always auto).